# sorting datetime columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe table that has columns containing datetime information.
As you can see from the table below, the 2019-xx field is between the years 2018 and 2016 so I need to arrange it properly.

I tried to use `.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)` but in vain
(I don't know why it has no effect at all).

Dataframe:

```
                      2017-12-31   2018-12-31  2019-12-31   2016-12-31  2020-06-30
Unnamed: 0
WaterFlow   -26084000.0 -257404000.0 -84066000.0  135075000.0         NaN
trailing1HourWaterFlow         NaN          NaN -84066000.0          NaN   6823000.0
```

- The problem is that:

  1. I don't know how to arrange columns orders when it's represented as
     datetime info.
  2. The table above seems strange since that `"Unnamed: 0"` row is empty
     and there's a space between the columns and rows unlike other
     ordinary dataframes.

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need convert the columns to datetimes, then do the sorting. If `Unnamed: 0` is the index name you can remove it by using [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.sort_index(axis=1).rename_axis(None)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the solution! It finally solved my problem thank you again.